# Java compiler project

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation, nullpointerexception

I'm making a project which will compile Java source files when ran.

The issue I'm having is that the `StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);` line throws a NullPointerException.

Can anyone help fix this?

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();

DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();

StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(
        diagnostics, null, null);

System.out.println("Searching for scripts...");

File[] javaFiles = src.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File src, String name) {
        return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java");
    }
});

Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager
        .getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(javaFiles));

JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager,
        diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace.

Comment: when 2/3 arguments are nulls there's no surprise that NPE may be thrown...

Comment: @dantuch, the arguments he has set to null are allowed to be.

Comment: From the Javadoc of `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()`: `**Returns:** the compiler provided with this platform or null if no compiler is provided`. This is probably the problem - `ToolProvider` isn't very reliable, and even if you _know_ that there is a compiler on your system, `ToolProvider` can't find it and is returning `null`.

Comment: See also the [STBC](http://pscode.org/stbc/) & especially [(Class-path) Configuration](http://pscode.org/stbc/help.html#configuration). It uses the `JavaCompiler` API &  comes with source.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html#getSystemJavaCompiler%28%29) of `getSystemJavaCompiler()`:

> Returns:
>   the compiler provided with this platform or null if no compiler is provided

The most probable cause of a non-existing system compiler is that you are executing the program in a JRE (Java Runtime Enviroment) which does not provide a compiler. Try using a JDK (Java Development Kit) environment instead.

Comment: Ah I think you are correct since I'm running it in eclipse and haven't changed that setting! If I wanted this to work for any machine with JDK installed, would I need to edit the build path or something?

Comment: @Ciphor in eclipse you have some .cfg or .ini file where java path is specified. Change that to point to the JDK.

Comment: @dantuch that wont solve my problem if I ant this to work with any version of JDK that supports this on many machines.

Comment: I've figured out how to add a specific JDK to the build path, just not sure how to do it for any version.